# How to identify the element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I've been tinkering with Selenium (Python) for the day working on a project. I'm stuck trying to click on a link of the webpage because I'm unable to retrieve the element by any of the ways I've found until now.

The link is this:

```
<p>
<a href="0_fr.asp?contenido=0actunor.asp" target="mainFrame"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#CC9900">
<b>Base de datos de Disposiciones Vigentes</b></font></a>
</font>
</p>
```

Now, I've tried these things so far, and all give me NoSuchElementException:

1. driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href=0_fr.asp?contenido=0actunor.asp]")
2. driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div:contains("Base de datos de Disposiciones Vigentes")')
3. same as 1) but copying and pasting CSS selector alone as a String
4. by link text and partial link text using the content between  **and**
5. by using id just in case it does something.

And several more found across other StackOverflow questions and online guides to build my own css selectors and such, but I don't know any HTML or CSS so it's been a bit difficult to follow them.
I can provide more information if needed, but i'm unable to link the webpage as you would have to log in and it's a job thing.

Any help or places to search for more information are greatly welcome!

SOLVED: The problem was that the link was inside a frame, which was inside another frame. I just hade to use driver.switch_to.frame("frameName") twice, then use css_selector normally and works as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element is `<a>` element and by all possible means you will interact i.e. click on it. Ideally to invoke `click()` on any element using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='contenido'][href*='actunor'][target='mainFrame'] b"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'contenido') and contains(@href, 'actunor')][@target='mainFrame']//b[text()='Base de datos de Disposiciones Vigentes']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

As you are observing *TimeoutException* inducing *WebDriverWait* you need to address [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511) first following the discussion in [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Now instead of giving the NoSuchElement Exception it's returning "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException"  with no message.  it is a step forward i suppose!

Comment: @Alberefe Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Hi, @DebanjanB !
Thanks for the sources! After trying for a while and reading the links you gave me i found the problem.
The link was inside a frame which was at the same time inside another frame. I just had to switch.frame() twice, then click on it by css_selector normally. 

Thanks a lot for the help and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command.

driver.find_element_by_link_text("Base de datos de Disposiciones Vigentes")